# Connect to Outlook via SQL

Tags: sql-server, outlook

Can you open a connection to Outlook and query through emails within certain folders? I'm trying to connect to an email account not on my local machine so I can count all emails with a certain subject on a daily basis. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: There is no ODBC or OleDB data-source that exposes Outlook's data. However you can have a SQL-like experience by iterating over Outlook items using the COM Automation API and Linq.

Comment: I think SQL is the wrong tool for this.  I'd recommend researching using Powershell and Exchange.  Powershell can also communicate with SQL Server and should be able to bridge the gap between the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

### Python + SQLite.

You can use Python to run [SQL over Outlook](https://github.com/pydemo/sql-over-outlook)

You can connect to specific folder and download all emails from it.

Then you have couple of choices:

- Count emails using Python `for` loop
- Extract all email subjects into SQLite table and execute SQL over it

### In this example

I was looking for specific info (elapsed time) in a body of the emails:

```
Target: Snowflake - DY_Position_TD
Started On: 2019-07-24 12:00:20
Ended On: 2019-07-24 13:12:18
Records Added: 4,180,659
```

#### After extract to SQLite table i used this query:

```
SELECT tname, asodt, max(  Cast ((  JulianDay(ended_on) - JulianDay(started_on)) * 24 * 60  As Integer)) diff 
from stats 
group by 1, 2 
order by 1 desc,2 desc
```

### Result (was generated daily):

```
C:\temp\Python37-32>python max_elapsed.py
DY_Position_TD,  2019-07-23      71
DY_Position_TD,  2019-07-22      67
DY_Position_TD,  2019-07-19      79
DY_Position_SD,  2019-07-23      6
DY_Position_SD,  2019-07-22      6
DY_Position_SD,  2019-07-19      6
DY_FinancingPosition,    2019-07-23      16
DY_FinancingPosition,    2019-07-22      15
DY_FinancingPosition,    2019-07-19      15
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Invantive SQL by reading/writing between a Microsoft SQL Server data container and the running Outlook instance ([available tables](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/outlook-data-model/webhelp/index.html)). Disclaimer: I work on Invantive SQL.

Sample query:

```
create or replace table contacts@sqlserver
as
select *
from   contacts@outlook
```

Remember to start Outlook first and make sure the needed stores are available in the Outlook profile.

For mails, use something like:

```
select *
from   mails@outlook
where  subject like '%my hot topic%'
```

The query can be optimized by providing the folder ID or store ID as table function parameters:

```
select *
from   mails(folderEntryId => VALUE, storeEntryId => VALUE)@outlook
```

Values can be found in `stores@outlook`, such as:

```
select mal.subject
from   stores@outlook ste
join   mails@outlook(storeEntryId => ste.storeid) mal
where  ste.displayname = 'Camera'
```

The reverse direction is also possible, like inserting or updating mails into Outlook using `insert` or `update`.